# How do I find matching data in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I am trying to find some files listed in a big Excel workbook.

On Sheet 1 I have the list of all the files with full path.

```
C:\A\B\01.xlsx
C:\A\C\02.xls       
C:\A\D\03.zip       
C:\A\E\04.jpg
C:\A\F\05.gif
C:\A\G\06.xlsx
```

On Sheet 2 I have the names of files that I want, but not the entire paths.

```
02.xls
04.jpg
```

On Sheet 2, I would like to return the full path of the file with the same file name. I'd like the output to look like this:

```
C:\A\C\02.xls   02.xls
C:\A\E\04.jpg   04.jpg
```

Does anyone know how to do this in Excel?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
=IF(ISBLANK(D10),"",INDEX(FullPaths,MATCH(1,IF(SEARCH(D10,FullPaths),1,0))))
```

Where your range with the full paths is a names range called `FullPaths`. Your file names start in `D10` but you can put them anywhere. This needs to be entered as an array formula (ctrl+shift+enter).

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can accomplish this using the VLOOKUP function.

```
=VLOOKUP(Sheet2!A3;Sheet1!A3;1;TRUE)
```

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-function-HP010343011.aspx

I have tried your example and it seems to work.

Hope this helps!